# becomefirstResponder increases memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I present and dismiss keyboard, I observer that after 5 present/dismiss pairs, app memory usage goes up by ~200KB

Over time this can be a huge issue.

Is this a known observation? What can be done about this?